# How to manipulate datetime.time columns in python pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following df:

```
client_id   arrival   departure 
0700016     10:56:00  11:11:00  
7110265     15:42:00  15:57:00    
7110085     09:49:00  10:04:00     
7110317     11:24:00  11:39:00     
7100047     08:47:00  09:03:00         
7110259     14:57:00  15:12:00      
7110298     08:43:00  08:59:00      
7110315     00:00:00  00:00:00     
7110255     10:26:00  10:41:00      
7110314     00:00:00  00:00:00
```

The `arrival` and `departure` columns are in `datetime.time` format which, apparently, is something like this: `datetime.time(11, 11)` for the 1st observation in `departure`. I am trying to access some rows with arrival at `11:11:00` using the following code:

```
data2.loc[data2["departure"] == "11:11:00"]
```

However my output is empty, like there is no departure at 11:11:00. If anyone knows how do get access to certain rows with a specified departure I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Try this: data2.loc[data2["departure"].astype('str') == "11:11:00"]

Answer (score 0):

You might have an issue with the type casting.

Try

`data2['departure'] = pd.to_datetime(data2['departure'])`

then

`data2.loc[data2["departure"] == "11:11:00"]`

Updated:
Based on your error I belive your casting issue is with str and object

`data2.loc[data2["departure"].astype(str) == "11:11:00"]`

Comment: I'm getting this error: `<class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime`

Comment: updated, you might need to convert to str then

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `datetime` object in pandas series/dataframe. It doesn't play every nicely with Series operations as you already see. Use Pandas' `datetime/timedelta` type:

```
# use timedelta for time
df['departure'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['departure'].astype(str))

# then can compre with string:
df['departure'] == '11:11:00'
```

Output:

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
Name: departure, dtype: bool
```

Comment: It solves the problem but now I have something like: `0 days 11:11:00` for every row in that column. I know I can remove the `{} days` part but I believe it would be an extra operation.